# keycloak helm chart to use external database (LDAP)

Tags: postgresql, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, openldap, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am attempting to install a Keycloak Helm chart and would like to utilize an external data store such as LDAP instead of the default Postgres database. Is it possible to achieve this configuration, and if so, what steps should I follow?

When I disable the default Postgresql.enabled option in the Helm chart, I encounter the following error message.

```bash
helm install keycloak oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/keycloak --set postgresql.enabled=false
```

> ```
> WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /home/kube-user/.kube/config
> WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /home/kube-user/.kube/config
> Pulled: registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/keycloak:16.1.1
> Digest: sha256:efaa12a0e3fb0e8fe32243c67cc8e24bf1854282d10c76c6d02ce0b5f0f1f02e
> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: execution error at (keycloak/templates/NOTES.txt:93:4):
> VALUES VALIDATION:
> **keycloak: database
>     You disabled the PostgreSQL sub-chart but did not specify an external PostgreSQL host.
>     Either deploy the PostgreSQL sub-chart (--set postgresql.enabled=true),
>     or set a value for the external database host (--set externalDatabase.host=FOO)
>     and set a value for the external database password (--set externalDatabase.password=BAR)
>     or existing secret (--set externalDatabase.existingSecret=BAR)**
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As state by the error message this option doesnot enable connection to ldap, it disable the subchart postgresql and need external configuration to an existing postgresql.

To connect to ldap you could configure using UI [doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/)

Then to automate deployment you can export configuration and set it when deploying

```
helm install keycloak oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/keycloak \
       --set keycloakConfigCli.enabled=true \
       --set-file keycloakConfigCli.configuration=<path to your configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak needs a PostgreSQL database even when using LDAP as an externalized source of user accounts, as all configuration is stored in the database as well (such as the endpoints/settings for your LDAP). If you disable PostgreSQL within the chart, you need to provide a manual database configuration, for instance using the `externalDatabase`-parameters:
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak/#database-parameters